# Issue expanding raid6 array using storcli

Tags: raid6

I've got a RAID 930-16i 4GB RAID card.

I started originally with a single vd comprising of 4 x SSDs in RAID6

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
DG/VD TYPE  State Access Consist Cache Cac sCC     Size Name
-------------------------------------------------------------
0/0   RAID6 Optl  RW     Yes     NRWBD -   ON  6.984 TB VD_1
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I had 6 disks total in the system

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                                   Sp Type
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
134:0     1 Onln   0 3.492 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B MTFDDAK3T8TDT-1AW1ZA 02JG547D7A44712LEN U  -
134:1     2 Onln   0 3.492 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B MTFDDAK3T8TDT-1AW1ZA 02JG547D7A44712LEN U  -
134:2     0 Onln   0 3.492 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B MTFDDAK3T8TDT-1AW1ZA 02JG547D7A44712LEN U  -
134:3     3 Onln   0 3.492 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B MTFDDAK3T8TDT-1AW1ZA 02JG547D7A44712LEN U  -
134:4     4 UGood  - 3.492 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B MTFDDAK3T8TDT-1AW1ZA 02JG547D7A44712LEN U  -
134:5     5 UGood  - 3.492 TB SATA SSD N   N  512B MTFDDAK3T8TDT-1AW1ZA 02JG547D7A44712LEN U  -
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I went to add the 5th disk (134:4) to online-expand the RAID array which worked successfully:

```
./storcli /c0/v0 start migrate type=raid6 option=add drives=134:4
```

I now want to add the 6th disk. However, when I attempt to add it, I get an error:

```
./storcli /c0/v0 start migrate type=raid6 option=add drives=134:5
CLI Version = 007.1325.0000.0000 June 19, 2020
Operating system = VMkernel 6.7.0
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = None

Detailed Status :
===============

------------------------------------------------------
VD Operation Status ErrCd ErrMsg
------------------------------------------------------
 0 Migrate   Failed   255 Start Migrate not possible.
------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas why the error message when the previous disk expansion went OK?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as OP that I also struggled to diagnose. After performing my first successful expansion I attempted to add additional disks with the following command:

`./storcli64 /c0/v0 start migrate type=raid6 option=add drives=0:6-7`

Which responds:

```
------------------------------------------------------
VD Operation Status ErrCd ErrMsg
------------------------------------------------------
 0 Migrate   Failed   255 Start Migrate not possible.
------------------------------------------------------
```

I couldn't find an easy way to diagnose the actual fault. The only clue as to what might be going on is the following command:

`./storcli64 /c0/v0 show all`

You should get an output similar too:

```
VD0 Properties :
==============
Strip Size = 256 KB
Number of Blocks = 125002842112
VD has Emulated PD = Yes
Span Depth = 1
Number of Drives Per Span = 6
Write Cache(initial setting) = WriteBack
Disk Cache Policy = Disk's Default
Encryption = None
Data Protection = Disabled
Active Operations = Background Initialization (89%)
Exposed to OS = Yes
OS Drive Name = /dev/sda
Creation Date = 13-07-2021
Creation Time = 05:45:51 AM
Emulation type = default
Cachebypass size = Cachebypass-64k
Cachebypass Mode = Cachebypass Intelligent
Is LD Ready for OS Requests = Yes
SCSI NAA Id = 600304802411a602287fe50f14e63699
Unmap Enabled = N/A
```

In my case you can see:

`Active Operations = Background Initialization (89%)`

To get more details on this, execute:

`./storcli64 /c0/v0 show bgi`

This should give a similar output to the migration with:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
VD Operation Progress% Status      Estimated Time Left
-------------------------------------------------------
 0 BGI              89 In progress 17 Hours 53 Minutes
-------------------------------------------------------
```

It seems that once the migration completes, this does not mean the controller is ready, it must then run a background initialisation step.

Comment: Makes sense - thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've got no idea what has changed in the last 1 hour or so since I made my post, but I executed the command again (same command from my original post)

```
./storcli /c0/v0 start migrate type=raid6 option=add drives=134:5
```

and it's working - showing ~24 hours left before expansion completes.